# Ionic 2: Pass data from side menu to presented view

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm new to Ionic 2. I'm trying to figure out how to pass data from the side menu to the child view. When the user selects a menu item I want to pass some data to the view that is presented. I've searched throughout the Ionic 2 Documentation but haven't found an answer. The only thing I've figured out is that the data will have to be passed from the app.component.ts file in the openPage() function. I just don't know where to go from there. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can send data by NavController here is the example
in menu page:

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-list>
        <button ion-item (click)="page1()">
            menu1
        </button>

    </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

and in app.component.ts

```
page1() {
this.menu.close();
this.nav.setRoot(Page1, {param: 'Foo'});
```

}

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for